# importing a full project into another project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I want to use functionality of another project in android studio in my own project. That another project is not a library. Its a complete project. How can i use it in my project?

Comment: I think File -> New -> import project will do it

Answer (score 0):

You must copy all java classes and its xml to your new project. There is no other way I think.

Comment: I am tryin to use following library but getting error: https://github.com/kristijandraca/BackgroundMailLibrary

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy all the resources(images,xml,strings etc..),java files,merge the android manifest file etc..if NDK is used you have to copy the JNI files and all.

Comment: I am tryin to use following library but getting error: https://github.com/kristijandraca/BackgroundMailLibrary

Comment: You can just copy and paste all the files inside your project ..while using its file ..correctly import the file to use it. If you are facing any problem then post the error..and don't forget about pasting the Android Manifest as well

Comment: Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found. <a href="openFile">Open File</a>

Answer (score 0):

You download that sample atke the library from that sample add as module to your project and write the code in your app as it says. it works smooth for me.

Comment: Error:(2, 0) Plugin with id 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven' not found.
<a href="openFile">Open File</a>